# How can iodized oil be made?

Tags: organic-chemistry, solutions

I want to combine solid elemental iodine with olive oil, to form an iodized oil - what is called an iodostearic acid or iodooctadecanoic acid,  here the double bond in the oil becomes saturated by iodine. I have not done this before and I am looking for guidance on how to do this with basic kitchen tools. Would this be as simple as adding iodine and oil in the ratio of 8 parts iodine to 10 parts oil (as the iodine number for olive oil is around 80), and then waiting several hours or days for the reaction to take place? Is heat or some catalyst needed? Please advise! Thank you.

Comment: Why would you waste olive for that?

Comment: See also W: [Iodine value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iodine_value)

Answer (score 1):

Essentialy yes, this will work for an unsaturated acid. It will work better if you dissolve your acid substrate in a volatile organic solvent (ether or dichloromethane would be good) and stir it efficiently, wash with sodium thiosulfate solution to remove any unreacted iodine, then allow the solvent to evaporate.

Comment: Yes, but the OP was talking about starting with *olive oil* which **is** unsaturated but which will end up saturated if he adds enough iodine.

Comment: My bad. Edited my answer

Comment: doi:10.1016/S0140-6736(97)02427-6 might also be interesting, in that it (1) describes the consequence of switching oils (2) mentions the actual procedure, i.e. reacting hydroiodic acid with alcoholic esters of oil FAs